# How to add search filter in DashCode

Tags: javascript, dashcode

I have a list loaded from datasource in Dashcode and I added a search field. Also I've found filterPredicate option in the list.

How to bind all things together to make the search filter the list?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing Apple WWDC video I've found how to bind the search:

1. Set search predicate string to a target field in which the search will be done (e.g. name, description - depends on the datasource structure).
2. Open datasources, select a list and bind filterPredicate with the predicate property of the search field.

That's it.